# Pagination search in Erlang Mnesia

Tags: search, pagination, erlang, mnesia

For example, given record

```
-record(item, {
  id,
  time,
  status}).
```

I want to search the 1000 to 1100 items, ordered by time and `status =:= <<"finished">>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your queries look like. If you need to order by lots of different columns, then I'd consider using SQL instead of Mnesia.

But if you only need the kind of query you described, you should be able to use the [`ordered_set`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2) type of table to handle the ordering and [`mnesia:select/4`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-4) to handle pagination and the constraint.

Here's some untested code to give you the gist:

```
% time goes first because it's our primary sort key
-record(statuses, {time, id, status}).
...
create_table() ->
  mnesia:create_table(statuses, [
                        {attributes, record_info(fields, statuses)}
                       ,{type, ordered_set}
                       ]).

-spec fetch_paged(integer()) -> {[tuple()], continuation()}|'$end_of_table'.
fetch_paged(PageSize) ->
  MatchSpec = {#statuses{id = '$1', status = <<"finished">>, _ = '_'}, [], ['$1']},
  mnesia:select(statuses, [MatchSpec], PageSize, read).

-spec next_page(continuation()) -> {[tuple()], continuation()}|'$end_of_table'.
next_page(Cont) ->
  mnesia:select(Cont).
```

Basically, `mnesia:select/4` gives you a page of results and a continuation for the next page of results. There's not a built-in way to jump to the 1000th result like in a SQL DB, so if you needed that ability you'd build it yourself (keep an index of times so you can quickly look up that the 1000th time in your table is `{{2015,4,12},{23,53,8}}` and then use that as a guard when running `select`.

Comment: Very helpful. Cant image that there is no efficient way to jump to 1000th result directly

Comment: My (relatively inexperienced) impression of Mnesia is that you can view it as a NoSQL DB (where it totally makes sense that you can't ask for page 1000) or you can view it as a relational DB but without the top layers of interface that you'd get from a SQL DB like Postgres. So if you want Mnesia *and* those layers, you need to build them yourself. (Which is basically what BlackMamba is doing with that fetch/sort/slice operation. Imagine writing that into a gen_server that does a little caching.)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `mnesia:select/2` to select the objects which `status =:= <<"finished">>`, then you can use `lists:sort` to sort the results by `time`, at last you can use `lists:sublist/3` to subtract the element from `1000` to `1100`.

Here is the link:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-2
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-2
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sublist-3

Comment: You can use dirty_match_object vs select/2 for a nice speedup. Since you probably don't care about consistency in the use case of pagination. If your dataset is particularly large you will run out of RAM to do this. Youl need to use something like dirty_ / next/2.

Answer (score 0):

You might to use QLC Cursor, something like this:

```
order(table_name,[id,Direction]) ->
case Direction of
    descent -> fun(A,B) -> A#table_name.id > B#table_name.id end;
    ascent -> fun(A,B) -> A#table_name.id < B#table_name.id end
end;

select(universal,[Data_module,Table,Minor,Major,Order_by,Direction,Query]) ->
try
    if
        Minor == Major -> {error};
        Minor == 0; Major == 0 -> {error};
        true ->
            case apply(Data_module,order,[Table,[Order_by,Direction]]) of
                error -> {error};
                Order ->
                    Transaction = fun() ->
                        Query = qlc:q([X||X <- mnesia:table(Table)]),
                        Handler = qlc:sort(Query,[{order,Order}]),
                        Cursor = qlc:cursor(Handler),
                        if
                            Minor == 1 ->
                                Result = qlc:next_answers(Cursor,Major),
                                qlc:delete_cursor(Cursor),
                                Result;
                            true ->
                                qlc:next_answers(Cursor,Minor-1),
                                Result = qlc:next_answers(Cursor,Major-Minor+1),
                                qlc:delete_cursor(Cursor),
                                Result
                        end
                    end,
                    mnesia:transaction(Transaction)
            end
    end
catch
    Exception:Reason -> {error}
end.
```

The manual of QLC is here [Qlc:reference](http://erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html#cursor-1)
but this way isn't fastest way in production, for middle heavy load is enought (10000 connection per second it tested), but more you will got a problems within memory free space, you will need to rise it up